# Converting from engineering notation to double and REGEX, split a string into two parts; numbers and characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to write a method that converts from **engineering notation** to `double`. The case I have now is very special! I mean I am not going to look for powers like "Mega, Giga and ..." I am just looking for floating points.

Some valid examples of my Case are:

`1.0 A` should be `1`

`1.0064 mA` or `1.0064 Ma` should be `0.0010064` Note that I count both **M** and **m** as **mili**...that can be achived using `ToLower()` method. and that **A** or **a** counts as Ampere for current.

I have the same case for Voltage, so in that user can enter **V** or **v** instead.

again some valid cases:
`256ma`  `366 m a`      `10.665 uA`

So at the end before I pass this string to my converting method, I do `text.ToLower().Remove(" ", string.Empty);` this will hopefully leave me with a easy string to work on.

Now the second step is to split numbers from characters:
`10.665ua` should result in `10.665` and `ua` so then I can check for first character of `ua` against a list of allowed strings and find the power factor.

```
private List<string> AllowedCurrentStrings = new List<string>() { "a", "ma", "m", "ua", "u", "na", "n", "pa", "p" };
```

So I am looking for your help. first I need to know how to split numbers from characters and then group the characters into a string (Or do I need to do the later one?)

Or if you think my approach is not good, it would be nice to hear a better one from you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
    public double ConvertMeasure(string measure)
    {
        measure = measure.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
        measure = measure.Substring(0, measure.Length - 1);
        char m = measure.Last();
        if (char.IsDigit(m))
            return double.Parse(measure, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        double ret = double.Parse(measure.Substring(0, measure.Length - 1),
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        switch (m)
        {
            case 'm': return ret / 1E3;
            case 'u': return ret / 1E6;
            case 'n': return ret / 1E9;
            case 'p': return ret / 1E12;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the OP wanted to originally accept either `1.0 mA` _or_ `1.0 m` and get the same result - am I confused, or does this solution break in that case?

Comment: @CodeJockey: I think OP wants to convert any string composed by a double, an optional char (m, u, etc...) and a char for measure unit. So my function removes last char and convert double according to optional char. Is it OK in your opinion?

Comment: Well actually what I have to care about is user input...and why I am using that `List` for units is to check if user has entered valid strings. For example `1.005 mmA` obviously is not a valid string and should be taken care of. Also you can see that I have `"m"`, `"u"` and... as well  so the method should try to find this special cases. Anyway, Marco's answer solved a big part of the problems I had, I will try to improve the method now.

Comment: @Sean87: my point is that Marco's solution will convert `1.005 mmA` to `0.001005` (as will mine) but will parse `1.005 muA` as `0.000001005`, by taking the second-to-last alpha character as the multiplier. Mine will not match at all (it is invalid, after all). Marco's solution will fail to parse `1.005 m` (because there is no second-to-last character), but mine will parse it as `0.001005` - is this not what you wanted?

Comment: @Marco - I think that the list `AllowedCurrentStrings` includes `m`, `u`, `n`, and `p` because he wants to accept something like `1.005 m` and convert it to `0.001005d`. I believe the intent was to accept the `A` or `V` part of the unit as implied (but not required). If I have interpreted correctly, your solution will not properly parse `1.005 m` and will instead actually return `1.005` - an unconverted value. I may have misinterpreted the input requirement, though.

Comment: @CodeJockey: in every OP example I see meause unit... but I cannot be sure ;)

Comment: Thats right. I did not point out to that problem, so my orginal question has been answered good enough by marco. I will try to make the parsing reliable as much as possible for different inputs and if I had problems...I know that stack guys are always around :P

Answer (score 1):

Though string parsing may be a teeny bit faster over all, this can certainly all be done with regex. A solution using regex to parse the string and a dictionary to select the conversion factor, but which is essentially the same as the answer from @Marco with a few improvements functionally, would be:

```
public double ConvertMeasure(string measure)
{
    var re = new Regex(@"(?i)(?<value>-?[\d.]+)\s*(?<multiplier>[munp]?)\s*(?<unit>[avw]*)");
    var conversionFactors = new Dictionary<string, double> {
    { "", 1 }, 
    { "m", 1E3 }, 
    { "u", 1E6 }, 
    { "n", 1E9 }, 
    { "p", 1E12 } };

    var m = re.Match(measure);

    double value = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups["value"].Value);
    return value / conversionFactors[m.Groups["multiplier"].Value.ToLower()];
}
```

This ignores the case of the string and ignores whitespace (including tabs, which might result if someone were to cut-and-paste a value instead of typing it) between the number and the multiplier and the unit, but does not ignore whitespace within the "number" (that is, `1.234 mA` is fine but `1.2 34 mA` should not be fine IMO, yet is parsed as `1.234` with @Marco's solution - just be careful :D ). Additionally, it will still work if someone accidentally pastes extra non-numerical characters in front of the number, such as `=` or a surrounding set of parentheses.

Of course, neither solution as written will return the actual unit in any way. I am assuming since you were planning to allow "m", "u", etc. (without the unit) that you have something similar to a text box with "Amps" or "Amperes" next to it and want to allow someone to put in any of `1.3` `1.3A`, `1.3 u` or `1.3 uA` etc. Thus, you know what the base unit is - this solution will provide the conversion functionality and ignore the actual unit.

The character class `[avw]` in the regex specifies what units are allowed (in this case `a`, `v`, or ,`w`). If you want to prevent someone from ACCIDENTALLY putting `1.234 mV` into a field that expects Amps, you might modify the function to accept an "AllowedUnits" string parameter (like `a` or `v`), then inject that parameter into the regex in place of the `avw`, thus:

```
    var re = new Regex(@"(?i)(?<value>-?[\d.]+)\s*(?<multiplier>[munp]?)\s*(?<unit>[" + AllowedUnits + @"]*)");
```

...then pass `"a"` into any conversion for Amps, or `"v"` into any conversion for Volts, etc.

I have not tested it, but I think @Marco's solution will break if there is no unit (e.g. if the string only has `m`, `u`, `n`, or `p` instead of `mA`, `ua`, `nV`, etc.). I believe it will trim the unit because it cuts off the last character. If there is only one character (e.g. `u`) then it will lose that data! My solution will not only work regardless of the unit, but it will even work if you want to later support more units like `Hz`, `mol`, or `cd` - though moles and candelas may not be quite as common in an engineering context...

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: As written, my solution will actually not parse a string such as `1.005 muA` (because it is not valid) if you want to accept it as a value and return a converted double based upon the `m` prefix, you can change the `[avw]` in the regex to `[a-z]`. This will remove the checking for a _valid_ unit, and merely allow any number of letters (upper or lower case) after the first valid multiplier (`m`, `u`, `n`, or `p`).